# How to serve image in Next-Gen format in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Im doing some optimizing work in my react app, which will improve the performance of my APP.
As per google page speed insights, I need to do this point
1.**Serve images in next-gen formats**
But im getting those images from BE(backend).

```
                                <Img
                                  src={
                                    `${BASE_URL}/{data.id}`
                                      ? `${BASE_URL}/${data.id}`
                                      : defaultImg
                                  }
                                  className='img-fluid slider-st-img'
                                  alt='homeImg'
                                />
```

Like above example Im getting img src from backend, so now how to serve images in Next-Gen format.
Any one please suggest some thing here.